# Query mysql para segundos entre dos fechas agrupado por id de usuario, sin sumar los segundos entre rangos ya sumados

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando en el control de asistencia de los usuarios en mi plataforma, pero la suma me sale incorrecta debido a que algunos usuarios tienen varias pestañas abiertas en una misma página, y esto genera distintos logs del mismo usuario en el mismo rango. como en este ejemplo (logs de un mismo usuario en la misma página):

Los logs son de hora de acceso (in) y hora de salida (out) a una página.

[image: son los logs de entrada y salida de una página]

Para que se entienda el caso con claridad, si un usuario a estado en una página en dos pestañas distintas (con el mismo usuario), se crean dos logs por ejemplo:

| --------in------------ | -------out------------ | user_id |

| ---------------------- | ----------------------- | ------- |

| 2021-09-28 12:54:13 | 28/09/2021 15:00:19 | -- 1 -- |

| 2021-09-28 13:11:05 | 28/09/2021 15:12:22 | -- 1 -- |

Y lo que necesito es una query para que solo sume el tiempo en uno de los dos casos o sume el tiempo de "2021-09-28 12:54:13" a "28/09/2021 15:12:22" en vez de sumar ambas diferencias para tener el tiempo real de este usuario en la página, ahora mi query me devuelve la suma de las diferencias de ambos logs.

Esta es la query que utilizo:

```
SELECT
   nl1.user_id,
   SUM(ROUND(time_to_sec((TIMEDIFF( nl1.out, nl1.in ))))) AS seconds,  
FROM    
   wp_nub_user_logs AS nl1 
WHERE
   action = 'activity'
GROUP BY
   nl1.user_id 
ORDER BY
   seconds DESC;
```

La query suma la diferencia entre el "in" i el "out" de cada log agrupando y sumando estas sumas por id de usuario.

Necesito el total de segundos entre estos logs para generar el informe de asistencia, y que estos sean exactos.

¿Se puede añadir alguna condición para que en los rangos repetidos (en el caso de que sea el mismo usuario) no sume este tiempo? o tenéis alguna idea sobre una query o conjunto de queries para arreglar este caso de uso?

Agradecería muchísimo vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. Pareces decir que hay que ignorar algunos logs ¿? Si es así, ¿qué criterio debe seguirse para saber entre todos qué logs habría que ignorar en la suma? Pon un ejemplo aplicando el [método del patito de goma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_depuraci%C3%B3n_del_patito_de_goma).

Comment: he reducido la query a lo que realmente necesito mostrar, lo demás eran condiciones para otros temas a parte. He detallado mas bien el problema, por si no quedaba muy claro. Muchas gracias por tu comentario @A.Cedano